# MongoDB driver does not insert List<string> property of C# Model as an array

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a model that has a `List<string>` property:

```
public class SignalDoc_Header_NamedMeasures
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string SignalName { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateEnd { get; set; }
    public List<string> HeaderLines{ get; }

    public SignalDoc_Header_NamedMeasures()
    {
        HeaderLines = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

A data file parser will populate the model and store it in a collection

```
var dataHeader = new SignalDoc_Header_NamedMeasures
{
    Type = "Foo",
    SignalName = "xyzzy",
    Filename = fi.FullName,
};
…
// read through top part of a tricky text file to header line section
dataHeader.HeaderLines.Add(line);  // save the header line, other files might have multiple header lines.
… 
// parse file, tracking first and last timestamp of detail records
… 
dataHeader.DateStart = dateStart;
dataHeader.DateEnd = dateEnd;
… 

string collectionName = … some function of filename … ;
DropCollection(collectionName); // helper method

var h = AppDb.GetCollection<SignalDoc_Header_NamedMeasures>(collectionName);
await h.InsertOneAsync(dataHeader);
```

The `InsertOneAsync` works, but the inserted document does not contain an array for `HeaderLines`.  I use Compass Community to look at the db.

Q: What is missing or preventing the `List<string>` from being stored as an Array ?

Elsewhere, the `AppDb` is established as

```
    static MongoClient Client { get; set; }
    static IMongoDatabase AppDb { get; set; }

    static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
    {
        try {
            Client = new MongoClient($"mongodb://{ConnectionParameters}");
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Environment.Exit(-1);
        }

        AppDb = Client.GetDatabase(DatabaseName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the property requires a default `set` as well for MongoDB driver to 'honor' it.

```
public List<string> HeaderLines { get; }        // driver does not store
public List<string> HeaderLines { get; set; }   // driver stores as Array
```